# python method argument assertions

Tags: python

```
# function that prints hello your name is x and you are y years old
# name must be of type string and cannot be empty
# age must be of type int and cannot be 0
def functionX(name, age):
    if name == "":
        raise ValueError("name cannot be empty")
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError("name seem not to be a string")
    if age == 0:
        raise ValueError("age cannot be 0 (zero)")
    if not isinstance(age, int):
        raise TypeError("age needs to be an integer")
    print("hello ", name, ", you seem to be ", age," years old")
```

Is this a correct way of checking parameters provided to a function?

Comment: Yes those assertions meet the requirements in your code.

Comment: Use a [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) for the `isinstance()` checks. [ValueError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) is for the correct type but incorrect value

Comment: You could add type hints and use `mypy` to perform a static analysis.

Comment: The code is fine; the constraints themselves aren't common in idiomatic Python. The `print` call will only care that `str(name)` and `str(age)` don't raise exceptions. The empty string  and `0` can both be printed just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Making the code "cleaner" - adding type hints and using f string. Using a type checker like [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) will verify that the function caller is passing a string and an int.

```
def say_hello(name: str, age: int) -> None:
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError("name seem not to be a string")
    if not name:
        raise ValueError("name cannot be empty")
    if not isinstance(age, int):
        raise ValueError("age needs to be an integer")
    if age == 0:
        raise ValueError("age cannot be 0 (zero)")
    print(f'Hello {name} you seem to be {age} years old')


say_hello('jack', 12)
```